# master page generating a second title tag

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, title

I have a simple page inside a master page (well, in a master in a master).

In the top master I have the `head` tag with `runat="server"`, with a number of bits such as scripts, stylesheets, etc. and also a contentplaceholder. There is no title tag here.

In the page that uses this master, the content for the placeholder contains the 
`<title>pagename</title>` bit in it. I really have to set it in there.

Unfortunately when the page is rendered I get my title which is all good, but also get a second blank title tag - I presume dumped in there by .NET.

Is there any way of stopping this second title tag coming out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From memory, by virtue of putting the runat="server" on the `<head>` .Net automagically adds a `<title>` if there isn't one already.

I think (haven't tested it) is if in your masterpage you do

```
<head runat="server">
Blah
<title runat="server" visible="false"></title>
</head>
```

setting the Title tag explicitly in the Head of the masterpage and setting visibility to false works. I think.

Comment: cunning, didnt try that, although i suspect it would work.
ended up adding a seperate contentplaceholder for the title in the top master
<title><placeholder here</title> ...
works fine


thanks anyhow

Comment: I've just had the same problem and tried this fix. I can confirm that it does work. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to manually insert `<title>` to the head.
Just set `Page.Title = "title"` by code, or `<%@ Page Title="My Title" .. %>` by markup. 
ASP.NET will figure out the rest, and put the right title.

Answer (score 1):

I think using:

If you want to set title at page level

```
<%@ Master ... %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
  <title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="titleContent" runat="server" />
  </title>
</head>
```

Or,

If you want to set dynamic title at Master Page level.

```
<%@ Master ... %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
  <title>
    <asp:Literal ID="litPageTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
  </title>
</head>
```

is better way to make sure that empty second title tag is not generated.